# Where is the log when someone ssh my machine?

Tags: linux

When someone logs into my machine through `ssh`, where is that log file saved?

I am using Red Hat 4.8.5-4

Comment: `w`, `last`, `/var/log/auth.log`

Comment: I assume you mean Red Hat Enterprise Linux 4.8. [There is no Red Hat 4.8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux)

Answer (score 2):

Debian/Ubuntu: `/var/log/auth.log`

RHEL/Fedora: `/var/log/secure`

On `systemd` systems, all logs should be available in journal (accessible using `journalctl`).

Comment: Or on any systemd-based distro, run `journalctl _COMM=sshd`

Comment: @mattdm yes, it should do the job too, but the question is "where", not how to read them.

Comment: Well, in that case, the answer might be just "In the journal!", which isn't so helpful.

Comment: @mattdm Well, not arguing that this is well asked question, but yes, if there is not `*syslog`, they are only in journal, but it has also persistent store in some files. Otherwise they are also stored in the above mentioned files.

Comment: its not in the above mentioned files?

Comment: @user1767754: This is a question?